# How to block libwww-perl access in .net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

I was testing my website with online tools and one of the tools gave me this warning:

> Your server appears to allow access from User-agent Libwww-perl. Botnet scripts that automatically look for vulnerabilities in your software are sometimes identified as User-Agent libwww-perl. By blocking access from libwww-perl you can eliminate many simpler attacks. Read more on blocking Libwww-perl access and improving your website's security.

My web site is an ASP.NET MVC 5 site and I've simply added these lines to my "robots.txt" file.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-Agent: bingbot
Allow: /
```

However, the tool still reports the warning. What is the problem? I'm blocking all bots and just set bingbot to allow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you give the URL or Name of the online scanning tool I can only guess that it tried to crawl your pages while sending a `User-Agent: libwww-perl` - not if you block this in your robots.txt.

The Background for this is, robots.txt contains rules for well behaving search engines, not for malware. From http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html:

- robots can ignore your /robots.txt. Especially malware robots that
  scan the web for security vulnerabilities, and email address
  harvesters used by spammers will pay no attention.

I assume to "fix" this warning you must deny all requests for any page, image or file if the HTTP Headers contain `User-Agent: libwww-perl`. See [this question on configuring IIS](https://serverfault.com/questions/238664/block-bots-with-iis-7-5-and-8-0) to deny these requests without modifying your website.

Personally, I would not deny these requests as it is not worth the hassle. It is easy to change the User-Agent within a scanning tool and most already allow to mimic widely used browsers so the security gain would be very small. On the other hand, there may exist a good / legit tool that cannot be used because it does not fake its identity.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this into your file:

```
User-agent: Libwww-perl
Disallow: /
```

Comment: This won't stop botnet scripts which will pay no attention to the robots.txt, or worse, use it to find interesting targets for exploitation.

Answer (score -1):

Add robot.txt to your application and include that file within the root directory of your application. Add below to that robot.txt file

```
User-agent: Libwww-perl
Disallow: /
```

And For more information Please check information given below...
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Comment: This won't stop botnet scripts which will pay no attention to the robots.txt, or worse, use it to find interesting targets for exploitation.

Answer (score -3):

It can be blocked via an .htaccess Rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
```